# Create DOMNode to pass to google maps API using React or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

The Google Maps Info Window API accepts either a string or a DOMNode as an argument. I can use `document.createElement()` to generate a DOMNode, but that quickly explodes into many lines of code as the information I want to include there increases.

This is my createInfoWindow method for example:

```
  _createInfoWindow(id, location) {
    ...
    let button = document.createElement('button')
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Add to Itenerary'))
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', myFunction())
    let content = document.createElement('div')
    ...
    content.appendChild(button)
    return new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content })
  }
```

It would be nice to be able to generate a DOMNode that I can pass as an argument to the google maps api that is less verbose. I'm writing this app in React, so React is ideal, but whatever works - if there's a way to generate a DOMNode in jQuery, I'd like to know that as well. The above example is missing several lines of code that create a bunch of DOMElements and append them to content.

Comment: You might want to consider looking at the existing "react-google-maps" package. They are React components that wrap Google Maps API, including InfoWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd probably be best to write your own React component that contains your content, captures a ref to its DOM element, instantiate the google.maps.InfoWindow in componentDidMount(), and pass it the reference to the DOM element. Something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class InfoWindow extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.infoWindowApi = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: this.infoDiv })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.infoWindowApi && this.infoWindowApi.close();        
    }

    render () {
        const { id, location, onButtonClick } = this.props;

        return (
            <div ref={ref => (this.infoDiv = ref)}>
                <h2>Info</h2>
                <p>${location}</p>
                <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Add to Itenerary</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default InfoWindow;
```

...elsewhere in some container component:

```
<InfoWindow
  id={someId}
  location={theLocation}
  onButtonClick={() => this.onInfoWindowClicked(location)}
/>
```

...or if you must resort to jQuery, simply create a quick content DIV and pass to InfoWindow:

```
var contentDiv = $('<div><h2>Info</h2><button>Add to Itinerary</button></div>').click(myFunction);

// [0] to extract first (and only) DOM element inside the jQuery selector
var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentDiv[0] });
```

Comment: Here's the render function on my Map component. `return <div id='map'/>`. I'd prefer to leave it that way and add a DOMNode generated by JavaScript, jQuery, or React to `google.maps.InfoWindow( { content } )`

Comment: Otherwise it get's complicated to call things like `infoWindow.close()`, for example when clicking on another marker.

Comment: Also, I'd just like a deeper understanding of how to juggle React Elements and DOMNodes, or know more about how to use jQuery to generate DOMNodes.

Comment: IMHO, it will be easier for you to work with Google Maps in a "React way" instead of trying to work with React the "Google Maps way", if you know what I mean. Mixing direct DOM manipulation and React is not ideal, and you're discovering why through these "juggling" efforts. You have to play in the React lifecycle, not attempt to skirt around it or prop it up with calls into jQuery or document.createElement.

Comment: The best place to deal with DOM (if you must) in a React component is in componentDidMount, which is called after the DOM elements described in render have been created. Whether you break out into a separate InfoWindow component, or keep it all inside one big Map component, is up to you. But in any case, you need to get a DOM "ref" to your content div, and pass then pass that reference to google.maps.InfoWindow.

Comment: My app is currently working. `document.createElement()` is currently the most effective way for me to create the content of an infoWindow, given the architecture of the app. I'm looking for a more concise way, without altering the architecture of the app. I understand that doing things in a "google maps way" instead of a "React way", that's a good way of putting it.

I would like to get a DOMNode, without rendering anything into the DOM, exactly like I do with `document.createElement()`

Comment: Should I try re-posting with only a jQuery tag and no React tag?

Comment: In that case, I think you'll probably want to continue using document.createElement() or $() as normal. Still, best place to do stuff like this is in componentDidMount() (called only once, on client, and DOM elements already created).  If you have to destroy or detach DOM/jQuery stuff, do so in componentWillUnmount().  Best of luck, sounds like you're not too far off.

Comment: I actually don't know how to use `$()` to create a DOMNode (or don't remember). Can you point me to a resource?

Comment: var someDiv = $('<div>Hello</div>');  // someDiv[0] is actual DOM element inside the jQuery selector

Comment: `$('<div>Hello</div>')` is not a DOMNode. It's an object.

Comment: Add [0] to get the DOM node

Comment: Ah, excellent! If you post that, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: OK, added as alternative answer at bottom. Good luck!